# Laravel Horizon in subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

If I configure Laravel Horizon to run in a subdomain, what prefix should I use?

I did test leaving the value blank but ajax requests are not pointing to the subdomain.

[image]

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem?

Comment: I've found that it seems to actually need a full domain instead of "subdomain." So, if you want it to be `https://devtools.example.com/horizon/dashboard`, you need to set it to `'devtools.example.com'` instead of `'devtools'`.

Answer (score 3):

If you configure horizon to run in a subdomain Clear config and cache using artisan command: `php artisan config:clear` and then refresh the page, hope this will fix your issue!